# Kiddush where no one person drinks a cheekful?

Tags: halacha, kiddush

Suppose someone makes kiddush and distributes all the wine evenly to everyone at the table, including himself, in small cups; but there were enough people that no one person received/drank a cheekful. Would someone fulfill their mitzvah of kiddush after-the-fact (yotzei bedieved) this way?

Answer (score 5):

See [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chayyim 271:14 with Mishnah Berurah (especially paragraph 73)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.271.14?with=Mishnah%20Berurah) where it is explained that *bedi’avad* they fulfill their obligation of *kiddush* if they act in the way you have described.